# Better to excavate in the spring or winter?

Tags: excavation

This is a somewhat subjective question, so I am looking for a general principle rather than a specific, exact answer.

In New England, the building season is mostly the spring and summer. So, winter is off peak. This makes it easier and cheaper to find contractors during the winter. On the other hand, excavation during the winter is harder because the top 4 feet or so of soil freezes. So, on one hand it is cheaper because it is off peak, but on the other it is more expensive because of frozen ground. Which factor dominates? Are there other factors that are key? Should I prefer doing an excavation in the winter or spring?

The scope of the excavation is about 800 cubic yards.

Comment: That might depend on what the excavation is for. If it is for the foundation of a building then spring would make more sense because you don't (normally) want to pour concrete on frozen ground.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** Insulate the excavation area now and dig later.

---

Excavating in the winter is difficult only if you don't prepare the site. Lay down insulating blankets and/or straw over the entire area to be excavated prior to freeze. This will keep frost to a minimum and allow excavation at any time, such as when contractor prices are lower. Even if you're late and miss the freeze, insulating later allows ground heat to thaw some of the frost.

Excavating early means that the frost now exists at footing/slab level when it comes time to build. This presents its own set of complications, such as difficulty burying plumbing and drain tile and having to pour concrete on frozen ground. Better to have freshly-dug soil at that point, get footings and plumbing laid, and backfill.